# Can lisp code executed via (load ...) access it's own file path?

Tags: path

If a script runs using `(load /path/to/file.el)`, is there a way for the script that runs to access it's own path? (similar to Python's `__file__`)

---

Asking this because I'd like to construct a relative path from a `.dir-locals.el` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes

The variable `load-file-name` https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/How-Programs-Do-Loading.html contains the name of the file that is being loaded.

or `buffer-file-name` https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-File-Name.html as a local variable in the buffer saying where it is visiting or as a function that returns the file path from the buffers name.

Comment: This works on `load` (so that answers the question). Unfortunately after further investigation, the the logic that loads `.dir-locals.el` inserts the file into a temporary buffer then calls `(read (current-buffer))` AFAICS there is no way to access this information without advising code that loads `.dir-locals.el`